# Can Aggregate be used in Mongo 3.6 without cursor?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm using Mongoose 5 and Mongo 3.6.
Earlier I was able to use:

```
aggregate.exec(callback);
```

But now it gives the following error:

```
The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
```

I don't want to use cursor as it doesn't offer any method to handle all data at once. (Correct me if I'm wrong!) How can aggregates be used in Mongo 3.6 with bulk data at once.

Comment: I don't think anything under the hood changed in 3.6 (related to this problem, anyway). Aggregates have always used cursors to get the results and the cursor has always grabbed batches of data at a time. The API `cursor` parameter is now required (although you can set it to an empty object, which seems to defeat the purpose of making it required), but I don't think the actual behavior of the operation has changed.

Answer (score 0):

As per mongo docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/, 
you can't do that.

> Changed in version 3.4: MongoDB 3.6 removes the use of aggregate command without the cursor option unless the command includes the explain option. Unless you include the explain option, you must specify the cursor option.

Answer (score 0):

```
Media.collection.aggregate([{$match: query}], {$cursor: {}})
    .group({})
    .toArray(cb)
```

resolve it like this

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.